# Can we remove a Block (West, East, North or South block) out of a DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform, docklayoutpanel

I like DockLayoutPanel cos it's quite solid. However, there's a big problem.

That is how to  remove a Block (West, East, North or South block) out of a DockLayoutPanel?

Let say, i got this code

```
   <g:DockLayoutPanel ui:field="centralDockLayoutPanel">
         <g:center>
               <g:LayoutPanel ui:field="mainPanel"/>  
         </g:center>
         <g:east size="200">
                <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="happyHTMLPanel"  width="100%" height="100%"> 
                 Some more widgets here
               </g:HTMLPanel> 
         </g:east>
   </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

I want to remove the East block out of the centralDockLayoutPanel. So i tried

```java
getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().remove(getView().getHappyHTMLPanel());
```

But that doesn't work

```java
getView().getHappyHTMLPanel().setVisible(false);
```

also doesn't work

Can we remove a Block (West, East, North or South block) out of a DockLayoutPanel?

Comment: so you would like to remove not only the panel itself, but also want to "relayout" the other widgets so they take the spare place after the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do :

```
getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().remove(getView().getHappyHTMLPanel());
getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().forceLayout();
```

Or you can hide your panel:

```
getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().setWidgetHidden(getView().getHappyHTMLPanel(), true);
getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().forceLayout();
```

Comment: thax u very much, 1 small quest, how can i add it back?

Comment: i tried getView().getCentralDockLayoutPanel().addEast(getView().getHappyUserHTMLPanel(), 300); but got err "no widget may be added after the CENTER widget

Comment: Perfect, Thax you a lot.

Comment: In this case maybe it would be better for you to hide your widget, instead of removing it. I have updated the answer, where you can see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I always make their size between zero and non-zero, representing hidden and display respectively. By that, you can even add some animations when changing the size of the children.